# Angular 7 passing parameter in url, sending data as parameter in the url from backend to angular frontend

Tags: angular, routes, angular-routing, angular-router

I am using Angular 7 as my frontend and django as my backend, I am passing the cart id in the url as a parameter (for eg: http://localhost:4200/cartModule/cartId).
Earlier i was sending the id as query params (for eg: http://localhost:4200/cartModule/?id=cartId).

when I send http://localhost:4200/cartModule/cartId , in angular it redirects to http://localhost:4200/auth/carts/cart .

In my lazy-load.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [   
{path: 'auth', loadChildren: '../auth/auth.module#AuthModule'},
{path: '**', redirectTo: 'auth/carts/cart'},
```

]

In my auth.module.ts

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [{ 
  path:'',component: AuthComponent, children: [
    {path: 'carts', loadChildren: '../carts/cart.module#CartsModule'},
  ]}
```

]

In my cart.module.ts,  { CartRouterModule } from './cart.router'; is imported in Modules ,

```
const materialWidgetRoutes: Routes = [
{ path: 'cart', component: CartComponent ,data: { animation: 'cart' }},
```

above is cart.router.ts

I found these files interlinked and responsible for the routes.
I want http://localhost:4200/cartModule/cartId to get redirect to http://localhost:4200/auth/carts/cart/cartId , so that it includes id of the cart also in url , it shouldnt redirect to http://localhost:4200/auth/carts/cart , removing the /cartId

Please help.
Thanks